# How to use LoopBack Android SDK to create model with GeoPoint

Tags: android, loopbackjs, geopoints

I want to use Android SDK of LoopBack to create model with GeoPoint but I have stuck here for several hours. I tried to use com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint but it somehow crashes with my AndroidStudio and I do not know how to solve those issues. Could anyone tell me how to create GeoPoint object in Java for GeoPoint on LoopBack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoPoint returned from LoopBack is a HashMap. It's work very well for me. You need to create class of model with getter and setter and repository of model, read this: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Android+SDK#AndroidSDK-CreatingyourownLoopBackmodel

this is in model class:

```
private HashMap<String, Double> deviceCoordinate;
```

this is in class where I make the request:

```
String coord = "" + device.getDeviceCoordinate().get("lat") + " : " + device.getDeviceCoordinate().get("lng");
```